# I am using ffmpeg java library to convert captured screenshots to video. Video output is blurry

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, video, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg java library to convert captured screenshots to video. Video which is generated as output is blurry.

I am using bit rate as 9000, frames per sec as 25 and video size as that of desktop screen size.

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue.

P.S. I cannot use ffmpeg.exe and command line due to certain restrictions and hence I am opting for ffmpeg java library.

Any suggestions on the issue or suggestions on any better approach will be helpful.

```
    import java.awt.AWTException;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    import java.awt.Robot;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Date;
    
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    
    import org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec;
    import org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder;
    import org.bytedeco.javacv.OpenCVFrameConverter;
    
    public class ScreenRecorder{
    
        public static boolean videoComplete=false;
        public static String inputImageDir="inputImgFolder"+File.separator;
        public static String inputImgExt="png";
        public static String outputVideo="recording.mp4"; 
        public static int counter=0;
        public static int imgProcessed=0;
        public static FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder=null;
        public static int videoWidth=1920;
        public static int videoHeight=1080;
        public static int videoFrameRate=3;
        public static int videoQuality=0; // 0 is the max quality
        public static int videoBitRate=9000;
        public static String videoFormat="mp4";
        public static int videoCodec=avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4;
        public static Thread t1=null;
        public static Thread t2=null;
        public static JFrame frame=null;
        public static boolean isRegionSelected=false;
        public static int c1=0;
        public static int c2=0;
        public static int c3=0;
        public static int c4=0;
        
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            try {
                if(getRecorder()==null)
                {
                    System.out.println("Cannot make recorder object, Exiting program");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                if(getRobot()==null)
                {
                    System.out.println("Cannot make robot object, Exiting program");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                File scanFolder=new File(inputImageDir);
                scanFolder.delete();
                scanFolder.mkdirs();
                
                createGUI();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in program "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        
        public static void createGUI()
        {
            frame=new JFrame("Screen Recorder");
            JButton b1=new JButton("Select Region for Recording");
            JButton b2=new JButton("Start Recording");
            JButton b3=new JButton("Stop Recording");
            JLabel l1=new JLabel("<html><br/>If you dont select a region then full screen recording <br/> will be made when you click on Start Recording</html>");
            l1.setFont (l1.getFont ().deriveFont (20.0f));
            b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    try {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "A new window will open. Use your mouse to select the region you like to record");
                        new CropRegion().getImage();
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        System.out.println("Issue while trying to call the module to crop region");
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                }
            });
            b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    counter=0;
                    startRecording();
                }
            });
            b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    stopRecording();
                    System.out.print("Exiting...");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            
            frame.add(b1);
            frame.add(b2);
            frame.add(b3);
            frame.add(l1);
            frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(0));
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setSize(1000, 170);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
        
        public static void startRecording()
        {
            t1=new Thread()
            {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        takeScreenshot(getRobot());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Cannot make robot object, Exiting program "+e.getMessage());
                        System.out.println("Cannot make robot object, Exiting program "+e.getMessage());
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            };
            
            t2=new Thread()
            {
                public void run() {
                    prepareVideo();
                }
            };
            
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
            System.out.println("Started recording at "+new Date());
        }
        
        public static Robot getRobot() throws Exception
        {
            Robot r=null;
            try {
                r = new Robot();
                return r;
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Issue while initiating Robot object "+e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Issue while initiating Robot object "+e.getMessage());
                throw new Exception("Issue while initiating Robot object");
            }
        }
        
        public static void takeScreenshot(Robot r)
        {
            Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            Rectangle rec=new Rectangle(size);
            if(isRegionSelected)
            {
                rec=new Rectangle(c1, c2, c3-c1, c4-c2);
            }
            while(!videoComplete)
            {
            counter++;
            BufferedImage img = r.createScreenCapture(rec);
            try {
                ImageIO.write(img, inputImgExt, new File(inputImageDir+counter+"."+inputImgExt));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Got an issue while writing the screenshot to disk "+e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Got an issue while writing the screenshot to disk "+e.getMessage());
                counter--;
            }
            }
        }
        
        public static void prepareVideo()
        {
            File scanFolder=new File(inputImageDir);
            while(!videoComplete)
            {
                File[] inputFiles=scanFolder.listFiles();
                try {
                    getRobot().delay(500);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                //for(int i=0;i<scanFolder.list().length;i++)
                for(int i=0;i<inputFiles.length;i++)
                {
                    //imgProcessed++;
                    addImageToVideo(inputFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
                    //String imgToAdd=scanFolder.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+imgProcessed+"."+inputImgExt;
                    //addImageToVideo(imgToAdd);
                    //new File(imgToAdd).delete();
                    inputFiles[i].delete();
                }
            }
            
            File[] inputFiles=scanFolder.listFiles();
            for(int i=0;i<inputFiles.length;i++)
            {
                addImageToVideo(inputFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
                inputFiles[i].delete();
            }
        }
        
        public static FFmpegFrameRecorder getRecorder() throws Exception
        {
             if(recorder!=null)
             {
                 return recorder;
             }
             recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(outputVideo,videoWidth,videoHeight);
             try
             {
             recorder.setFrameRate(videoFrameRate);
             recorder.setVideoCodec(videoCodec);
             recorder.setVideoBitrate(videoBitRate);
             recorder.setFormat(videoFormat);
             recorder.setVideoQuality(videoQuality); // maximum quality
             recorder.start();
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Exception while starting the recorder object "+e.getMessage());
                 System.out.println("Exception while starting the recorder object "+e.getMessage());
                 throw new Exception("Unable to start recorder");
             }
             return recorder;
        }
        
        public static OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage getFrameConverter()
        {
            OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage grabberConverter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();
            return grabberConverter;
        }
        
        public static void addImageToVideo(String imgPath)
        {
            try {
                getRecorder().record(getFrameConverter().convert(cvLoadImage(imgPath)));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Exception while adding image to video "+e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Exception while adding image to video "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        
        public static void stopRecording()
        {
            try {
                videoComplete=true;
                System.out.println("Stopping recording at "+new Date());
                t1.join();
                System.out.println("Screenshot thread complete");
                t2.join();
                System.out.println("Video maker thread complete");
                getRecorder().stop();
                System.out.println("Recording has been saved successfully at "+new File(outputVideo).getAbsolutePath());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Recording has been saved successfully at "+new File(outputVideo).getAbsolutePath());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception while stopping the recorder "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Imagepanel.java

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class ImagePanel
  extends JPanel
{
  private Image img;
  
  public ImagePanel(String img)
  {
    this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());
  }
  
  public ImagePanel(Image img)
  {
    this.img = img;
    Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
    
    setPreferredSize(size);
    setMinimumSize(size);
    setMaximumSize(size);
    setSize(size);
    setLayout(null);
  }
  
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    g.drawImage(this.img, 0, 0, null);
  }
}
```

CropRegion.java

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class CropRegion implements MouseListener,
        MouseMotionListener {

    int drag_status = 0;
    int c1;
    int c2;
    int c3;
    int c4;
    JFrame frame=null;
    static int counter=0;
    JLabel background=null;

    
    public void getImage() throws AWTException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(size));
        ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(img);
        frame=new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setLocation(0, 0);
        frame.setSize(size);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.addMouseListener(this);
        frame.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void draggedScreen() throws Exception {
        ScreenRecorder.c1=c1;
        ScreenRecorder.c2=c2;
        ScreenRecorder.c3=c3;
        ScreenRecorder.c4=c4;
        ScreenRecorder.isRegionSelected=true;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Region Selected.Please click on Start Recording button to record the selected region.");
        frame.dispose();
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        paint();
        this.c1 = arg0.getX();
        this.c2 = arg0.getY();
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        paint();
        if (this.drag_status == 1) {
            this.c3 = arg0.getX();
            this.c4 = arg0.getY();
            try {
                draggedScreen();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        paint();
        this.drag_status = 1;
        this.c3 = arg0.getX();
        this.c4 = arg0.getY();
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    public void paint() {
        Graphics g = frame.getGraphics();
        frame.repaint();
        int w = this.c1 - this.c3;
        int h = this.c2 - this.c4;
        w *= -1;
        h *= -1;
        if (w < 0) {
            w *= -1;
        }
        g.drawRect(this.c1, this.c2, w, h);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please update the question to show the main code you use for the conversion, it might help diagnose it.

Comment: I have added the complete code.

Comment: I can't see any ffmpeg code. How do you convert the images into video? If the images are blurry before you convert them, then the issue is not ffmpeg. Edit: please update your question to show formatted code. Becasue you pasted it all in one line we cannot tell what is comment and what is code.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Please see the complete code in the github link https://github.com/csanuragjain/recorder/tree/master/ScreenRecorder

Comment: Sorry, but links to GitHub or other off-site code repositories are not allowed for questions, and instead all pertinent code should be posted in your question as code-formatted text, preferably as a valid [mre] (please read the link which will explain this construct, how to make one, and why doing this can help you get better an quicker answers).

Comment: Note: For busy screen captures a bitrate of 9000 might be ok for 720-1080p resolution for static vides, but for detailed video or at higher resolutions (1440, 4k etc) it will start to look blurry very quickly. The bitrate should also scale up based on the resolution (not a fixed 9000 rate). Set the bitrate to 20,000-30,000 and see if it improves. If so then consider using a lower resolution, an increased bitrate, and lookup the advantages of different codecs.

Comment: No luck. Tried with lower resolution and higher bit rate but there was no change in video quality. Video was blurry.

Comment: 1) You are using the encoder "mpeg4". It outputs MPEG-4 Part 2 video; an old, legacy format. Is this what you want? 2) What is the unit in `public static int videoBitRate=9000;`? bits? kilobits? If it's bits that's low for mpeg4 and you may want to add another `0`.

Comment: I have made the vidioBitRate to 9000000 and reduced video size to match the resolution  of desktop screen yet the output appears to be blurry video. There aren't any examples available for ffmpeg java library hence I am stuck.

Comment: Hi, @HovercraftFullOfEels Can you please reopen my question for answers. I have added the neessary code so that it can be easily understood and reproduced by anyone.

Comment: 1) Did you check that the input images are not blurry? 2) Does it look better if you change `AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4` to `AV_CODEC_ID_H264`? You may have to set pixel format to yuv420p to be able to decode the resulting output.

Comment: Hi @llogan I have thoroughly verified that the pictures are not blurry and I have tried both the codec you suggested. I have also set pixel format to yuv420. Still I am seeing the same issue.

Comment: Is this behavior reproducible with the ffmpeg command-line tool? I know you are not using that, but this java stuff is an extra layer of complexity and it may narrow down the issue and make it easier to replicate the problem.